# Changing informtion from state onclick

Tags: reactjs

Simple React app.

When I click on the button I want to show the data from that state eg click the first button i want the details from the first object in "list state" (title - test1 duration 2mins.

So When you click "test1" cta I want to show "test 1 duration 2 mins" in another div. 
test 2 will equal "test2 duration 3mins". But I cant get the values when i click the button, only the "title" if I add the value to the button.

```
 this.state={
    list:[
        {
          title:'test1',
          duration:'2 mins'
        },
        {
          title:'test2',
          duration:'3 mins'
        },  
        {
          title:'test3',
          duration:'4 mins'
        },  
        {
          title:'test4',
          duration:'5 mins'
        }
      ]
 }

 changeList(e){
   var x=e.target.value;
   if (x=='test1'){
       console.log('duratiomn=-3')
   }
 }

 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Songselect list={this.state.list} changeList{(e)=>this.changeList(e)}/>
      </div>
    )
 }
}
```

```
const Songselect=(props)=>{
 return (
     <div>
        {props.list.map((item,index)=> <div><span name="test"> {item.title} 
         </span><button for='test' onClick={props.changeList} value= 
           {item.title}> select</button> </div>)}
     </div>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can maintain state for `selected` item.

```
selected: ''   //Add this in state
```

From `Songselect` component you need to send back `title` of selected item,

```
onClick={()=>props.changeList(item.title)}
```

And in the parent component should send props like,

```
<Songselect list={this.state.list} changeList={this.changeList}/>
```

Your `changeList` function should be,

```
changeList = (title) => {  //Use arrow function which auto binds `this`
  const selected = this.state.list.filter(data=> data.title === title)
  this.setState({selected:selected[0]})
}
```

You can show selected item in parent coponent like,

```
{this.state.selected &&
   <React.Fragment>
      <h2>
          Selected
      </h2>
      <div> Title : {this.state.selected.title}</div>
      <div> Duration : {this.state.selected.duration}</div>
   </React.Fragment>
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-davgsr)

Comment: Do you mind explaining something to me please?
I see if i remove the '{this.state.selected &&' part, by default some text display. How/Why does this statement only kick in once theres been a onClick? 
  {this.state.selected &&
                  <React.Fragment>
                      <h2>Selected</h2>
                      <div> Title : {this.state.selected.title}</div>
                      <div> Duration : {this.state.selected.duration}</div>
                  </React.Fragment>
                }

Comment: It's a condition. When `this.state.selected` true then print `<React.Fragment> <h2>Selected</h2> <div> Title : {this.state.selected.title}</div> <div> Duration : {this.state.selected.duration}</div> </React.Fragment>`. You can check more here - https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Answer (score 0):

You should try something with an arrow function like :

```
changeList = item => event = {
    console.log(item);    
}
```

Then in your `map` function you can call it like this :

```
{
 props.list.map((item,index)=> (
    <div>
        <span name="test"> {item.title} </span>
        <button for='test' onClick={props.changeList(item)}> 
            select
        </button>
    </div>)
)}
```